# example - functional in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

We were given the following example in our lecture:

Let $\mathbb{K}= \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. For all $F\in L^2(\Omega)^n$, $f_0 \in L^2(\Omega)$, the following identity
$$ <f, \varphi>= - \int_{\Omega} F(x) \cdot \nabla \varphi(x)dx + \int_{\Omega}f_0(x) \varphi(x)dx $$
for $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega)=W_{2,0}^1(\Omega)$ defines a functional in $H^{-1}(\Omega)=(H^1_0(\Omega))^*$ (=the dual space).
**Question:** What is meant by "functional" (I thought of simply a linear map in there) and how can I show this?

It continues: As $F$ is only in $L^2(\Omega)=H^0(\Omega)=W_2^0(\Omega)$, $div(F)$ is in general no regular distribution but we have $div(F) \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$.
**Question:** How do I show that $div(F)$ is no regular distribution? I already don't understand why it is a distribution at all? In this context, I also fail to see why the second part holds ($div(F) \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$)?

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: The linear map in question is $\varphi \mapsto \langle f, \varphi \rangle$. The other point may be a mistake, as $div F$ is a distribution, maybe what was meant is that $div F$ cannot necessarily be represented by a function.

Comment: about your question regarding $\div F$: how is it defined for $F \in L^2(\Omega)^n$?

Comment: @supinf I'm not sure how it is defined; we did not define it separately for this case, so I (maybe falsely) assumed that is defined as usual. If it helps - we defined $L^2(\Omega)^n$ as as the usual $L^2(\Omega)$ space but with the maps in it going from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R }^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 1):

A functional is a linear and continuous function from a normed vector space to $\mathbb K$.
In this case, $f$ is a functional if and only if $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$.

So you want to show that $f$ defined via $\varphi\mapsto \langle f,\varphi \rangle$ is continuous (linear is obvious).

What you have to do (i will not provide every detail) is to show that
$$|\langle f,\varphi\rangle | \leq C \| \varphi \|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}$$
for some constant $C$.
The estimate for the second summand can be shown by poincare,
and for the first you have to use some triangle inequalities and Hoelder.